# dhcp list dnsmasq without hostname for centos clients

Tags: centos, dnsmasq

I have a DHCP and DNS server setup with dnsmasq. Connected to it, I have Windows, Ubuntu and CentOS servers. Windows and Ubuntu servers are working normally, both the DNS and DHCP, however the CentOS servers are not. If I locally login to any of them, I can do a ssh to any of my other servers, but I can't do the opposite - I can't do a nslookup to these CentOS servers. Using bind, our old DNS and DHCP, it worked fine.

For example, trying to nslookup hull (which is a CentOS machine)

```
user@server:~$ nslookup hull
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53
** server can't find hull: NXDOMAIN
```

In hull, I have:

/etc/resolv.conf (Seems correct)

```
search company.intranet
nameserver    172.16.0.6
```

hostname

```
hull
```

/etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=hull
```

Something I noticed in my `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases`:

```
1475267373 ##:##:##:##:##:## 172.16.0.237 * *
1475276237 ##:##:##:##:##:## 172.16.0.196 * *
1475263184 ##:##:##:##:##:## 172.16.0.197 burnley *
1475262472 ##:##:##:##:##:## 172.16.0.158 karlebo *
```

The server does get a DHCP IP address but its hostname is not registered in the DNS. The other ones with names are Ubuntu and Windows machines, which are working.

My question is: am I missing something? Is there any sort of configuration I should do in these CentOS machines?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a variable called DHCP_HOSTNAME="SERVER_NAME" to `/etc//etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<INTERFACE>`.